Can the next POTUS legally reverse a previously passed and signed bill, like the TikTok ban?
Trump has claimed that he would save TikTok. But given that the circuit judges are to decide on the issue on December 6 and appear to be skeptical of TikTok's defense I would assume this would go to the Supreme Court, right?
The ban is supposed to become effective the day before Trump's inauguration. In such a case, does the POTUS even have any significant influence on whether Americans can continue to have access to TikTok?
Given that the Supreme Court has a conservative majority I am also curious as to how they would judge.

Have you studied the "Protecting Americans from Foreign Adversary Controlled Applications Act"? It seems like the president himself will make that call and probably can reverse his opinion at any time.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution: Can you clarify which provision of 15 USC 9901 gives the President that authority? I can't find it.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution but doesn't the term "President" refer to Biden when he made the call to ban tiktok rather than the next president?

@Kevin: Correction: 15 USC 9901 is the "Protecting Americans’ Data
from Foreign Adversaries Act". The separate "Protecting Americans from Foreign Adversary Controlled Applications Act" is in the "notes" of 15 USC 9901.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution: ByteDance, TikTok, and their subsidiaries, are specifically named in the Protecting Americans from Foreign Adversary Controlled Applications Act as companies whose apps are banned from app stores. The President can designate additional companies, but cannot remove the companies that were specifically listed. The only other thing the President can do is grant a one-time 90-day extension to the 270 days, but the President would be Biden when the 270 days are up, so that would not be up to Trump either.

@user102008 ByteDance renames itself to BitDance, and boom, now its no longer covered? :-)

@BufferInflow "doesn't the term "President" refer to Biden when he made the call to ban tiktok rather than the next president?" When congress grants or delegates some authority or discretion to the president, the authority rests in the office.  A subsequent president can undo or modify any presidential act under the authority or discretion (subject to other acts of congress such as the Administrative Procedure Act).  Statutory provisions that do not give authority or discretion to the president (or another executive officer) can only be changed by another act of congress.

@JonathanReez judging from your emoticon, I expect that you realize the response to your comment is "probably not," but to some extent that will depend on the precise language of the statute.  Even if the drafters of the statute didn't take into account the possibility of a name change, a judge probably would.

He can’t do it by executive order, but with Republican control of both House and Senate he can pass new legislation repealing the bill banning TikTok.

However the Bill that banned it in the first place was a Republican "baby" so to speak.

@SMSTJ Now that Republicans are expected to have control of both houses in the next Congress, many have vowed to take advantage of this to advance Trump's agenda. So even if they thought the ban was right before, if he wants it reversed they'll go along.

The Republicans don't have the necessary votes in the Senate to overcome a fillabuster (60), but I expect the fillabuster will be one of the first things to go.

@Schwern At least so far, they have vowed not to remove the filibuster

@Machavity The GOP has repeatedly demonstrated that their promises aren't worth the paper they're not written on.

@Shadur-don't-feed-the-AI They could have gotten rid of the Fillibuster everytime they were ins controll.
They dont wanna do cuz the the Dems wont reestablish int next time they get the majority. Both parties keep the Fillibuster ariund so they can use it next time they are the opposition

He can't reverse it by himself, but he has several options available.

He can urge Congress to repeal the law. Since Republicans will control both houses of Congress when Trump takes office, it's widely expected that they'll go along with most of the legislation he asks for. However, Republicans don't have a filibuster-proof majority in the Senate, so that may be an obstacle.

He can prevent enforcement of the law. The law has to be enforced by the Justice Department, who would fine app stores that continue to distribute the app. Trump could simply tell his Attorney General to sideline investigations of violations. Oregon Live says:



Leah Plunkett, a lecturer at Harvard Law School, said from her reading of the statute, the attorney general has to investigate violations but can decide whether or not to drag such companies to court and force them to comply.

Both techniques could be used in concert: if POTUS is actively trying to convince Congress to repeal the law, the AG will know about it and should not prioritize enforcement.

I highly doubt that Apple or Google (who run the only two significant US app stores) would want to take the risk. It's also hard for the current administration to guarantee that a future administration cannot impose penalties for current violations.

I don't think there's much risk if POTUS has made his intentions clear like this. And getting Congress to repeal the law will solve the problem of future administrations. Considering that Trump has a united Congress, something like this should not be hard to pass if he really wants it.

The House majority is extremely thin. They are not going to take this up before figuring out who the Speaker is, what to do about the budget, etc., and the Freedom Caucus is not going to make any of those things easy. By the time they get to the point of repealing something like the TikTok ban, we may already be starting the midterm campaign season.

Anything about the next Trump administration is pure speculation at the moment. We can only guess at how effective his control will be with the united Congress, even if it's a thin majority.

I sometimes think his outlandish nominees for the cabinet are a test to see how loyal the Senate will be.

@user102008: See my question on Law.SE .  A future administration imposing penalties for current violations may be legally problematic, depending on how the current administration's non-enforcement announcement was made.

@Brian It's also unclear that a campaign promise counts as an "appropriate authority".

@Barmar: A campaign promise is definitely not an appropriate authority.  The scenario I am envisioning is that the relevant enforcement arms could make a non-enforcement announcement in response to prompting by the Trump administration.  If such an announcement was made, it may prevent future enforcement action against companies that made decisions in reliance on that announcement.  Of course, this isn't a permanent state of affairs: Once the announcement is retracted, they'd have to stop relying on it.
